# .Net Core and Docker (Manage Application Settings)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have just started with docker. By spending lot time on docker videos and tutorials, finally I am able to create my first docker image (and push to docker hub). I am going to use that image for my dev environment shortly.

Question is:

I have few application configuration in my appsettings.json file. Those configurations are different for different environments. While I pull docker image on my dev environment, those configuration needs to be change according to dev environment. I am not sure how to manage this. Anyone have idea on this?

Few useful information:

1. I have .net core 2.0 application.
2. I am using, docker for windows (as requirement).
3. I'll host that container either in VM or on Azure App Service.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you pulling docker images into your dev env because you are going to extend them with your application or what? If you are going to create new images you can add your environment specific stuff that way...

Comment: yes, I am going to pull that docker image to my dev env.

Comment: Please try to clarify your quesiton. I did not understand anything from "While I pull docker image on my dev environment, those configuration needs to be change according to dev environment"

Comment: @Hasan: I have one docker image on docker hub which has my local configurations. Now, I want to deploy same docker image to my dev, stag & prod environment. Obviously, my connectionString and other values will be different for those environments. How can I change those values when I pull docker image on those environments. Should I create different images for different env? i.e. one for Dev, one for Stag

Answer (score 1):

have you already take a look at [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Docker/ASPNET-Core-and-Docker-Environment-Variables)

using **`ConfigurationBuilder`**

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json")
 .AddEnvironmentVariables()
 .Build();
```

Comment: yes, I already configured this. But the problem is; while using same docker hub image on different environment, we don't have option to define current environment. you got me?

Comment: Yes you do. You could use the configuration switch for `dotnet build` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) or you could prefix your call to `dotnet` (in the Entry Point stanza) with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging` (for production and staging, respectively)

Comment: @JamieTaylor there will be single build as docker image.

Comment: A single build for multiple environments?

Comment: Its important to note you will like name your appsettings files in all lowercase so if you want this to work add .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json")

Answer (score 1):

In your `Startup.cs`, if  everything is intact you should have this;

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json")
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .Build();
```

you have 2 environment names other than `Production`. Those are
- `Development`
- `Staging`

AspNetCore understands which environment you want from the value of the Environment Variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` which should be `Production`, `Development` or `Staging`

The environment you are in is important because AspNetCore picks the right settings json file based on your environment name. The code I shared above does this;

1. Load Settings from appsettings.json
2. Find environment specific settings file.

   - For Production  -> appsettings.production.json (note, this is usually not used)
   - For Development -> appsettings.development.json
   - For Staging     -> appsettings.staging.json
3. Override setting values based on the environment specific settings json file

So the solution to your problem is;

1. Make sure your appsettings.json file is filled for production values.
2. Add setting files for appsettings.development.json and appsettings.staging.json. Make the neccessary modifications in the contents of these files.

When you run your Docker container, override the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` based on the environment settings you would like to keep as I stated above.

Comment: I know above stuff. But the question is, while you are running under single docker image. How to OVERRIDE SETTING VALUES?

Answer (score 1):

When you `docker run` you can supply it a list of environment variables or a file with environment settings.  This allows you to set the variable you need modified when you start up your container.

Using the `-e` flag:

```
docker run -it -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Prod...
```

Using the `--env-file` flag:

```
docker run -it --env-file ./Prod.env ...
```

For reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file